# Issue in pytest_generate_tests() in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

## "conftest.py"

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--stringinput", action= "append", default = ["defaultstring"], help = "Input String")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "stringinput" in metafunc.fixturenames:
         metafunc.parametrize("stringinput",metafunc.config.getoption("stringinput"))
```

when we execute this code with passing the command line option "stringinput" as "pytest pytest_generate_test_example.py --stringinput="hello" ,it also execute the default values in the output.
The snippet of the ouput is as follows:--

pytest_generate_test_example.py::test_valid_string[defaultstring] PASSEDpytest_generate_test_example.py::test_valid_string[hello] PASSED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `argparse`'s "problem" not related to `pytest`. See the test script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Import')
parser.add_argument('test', action='append', default=['foo'])
args = parser.parse_args('bar'.split())

print args.test
```

It outputs `['foo', 'bar']`. I.e. `action='append'` appends to the `default` without clearing it first.

So to avoid the problem start with an empty `default` list and use your `defaultstring` if the argument is empty (there was no `--stringinput` command line parameter).